# Request URL Too Long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I getting this error "**Request URL Too Long**" when i tried to download the file. The url shows the data that i want to download but it doesn't download.

How can i solve **Request URL Too Long** error when downloading

my code

**Javascript**

```
 <script>
                    function DownloadIndexController(possID) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadIndex", "Poss")',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            data: { possID: possID },
                            type: "GET",
                            success: function (returnValue) {

                                window.location = '/DownloadIndex/Poss' + returnValue;
                            }
                        })
                    }
            </script>
```

**Controller**

```
  [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult DownloadIndex(int possID)
    {
        try
        {
            possFilename = possFilename.Replace(",", ",");
            string fullPath = Filelocation + possFilename;
            return File(fullPath,  System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, possFilename);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Which specific line of code in your question produces that exception?

Comment: I have debug and there's no error. only that error shows on the browser and on console

Comment: Hang on, are you returning a file as a `GET` operation, and then the file is appended to the url? Are you actually producing an URL which looks like `/DownloadIndex/Poss<file contents here>` ?

Comment: Try using an alert and showing the contents of `'/DownloadIndex/Poss' + returnValue`.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you are trying to do. Appending the file content to the url look rather strange, and most likely you will hit the browser limit for url length.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i am downloading a file on button click. I have alert '/DownloadIndex/Poss' + returnValue and get the file that i want to download

Comment: He knows that. He just wants to know the URL @MrJunior

Comment: And how large is that file?

Comment: @Hypnobrew I have a grid with rows and each rows have a button which you click to download. when you click the button,it must download a file

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 19.0 KB (19,530 bytes)

Comment: So now you're bulding an URL that is about 20K (the file contents + that small piece of the start of the URL from your javascript). We understand that you want to download the file but this is the wrong way to do it. Unless the file being downloaded contains "stuff to put in the url", then most likely you want to do what @glacasa has answered below instead. Appending the file **contents** to the url seems totally incorrect, unless this is just some obscure way of obtaining the rest of an URL.

Comment: I don't know the proper way of download a file.any proper way of downloading a file will be fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ajax to download a file in that way.
What you need to do is to generate a normal download link for every item in your grid, like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadIndex", "Home", new { possID = "123" }, null)
```

Where `Home` is the name of your controller, and you have to dynamically add the `possID` for every item instead of the hard coded `123` in my example.

Comment: Thanks this works. I removed all ajax call and it works. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you download the file using ajax, and then you redirect to an url containing the full file just after `'/DownloadIndex/Poss'`

You probably just want to redirect to the file, without using Ajax at all :

```
<script>
    function DownloadIndexController(possID) {
        window.location = '/DownloadIndex/Poss?possID=' + possID;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I have tested on IE,Edge and crome